# python selenium for facebook search bar

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I use selenium to login to Facebook. I am trying to put some keywords into the search bar and then get the results back. In the old version of the search bar, I could easily find the input by finding the `id` of the text input. However, in the new version of the search bar, I can't do the same trick. Anyone could handle this situation?

Comment: Just use another 'locator' technic, like CSS or XPATH. Also please include your code in the post.

Comment: check my answer for css-selector

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the input object with css selector by the text in `arai-label` as `"div[aria-label='Search Facebook']"`. See the console log below:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Search Facebook']").send_keys("We are Ankara")
>>>
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Search Facebook']").text
u'We are Ankara'
>>>
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[aria-label='Search']").click()
>>>
```